# Узнать размер таблицы MySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ребят, доброй ночи.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посмотреть сколько занимает места таблица MySQL без включения самого модуля mysql?

А так же как удалить данные из таблицы из консоли без включения модуля?

Модуль включить не могу, т.к. закончилась память на VPS.

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Спасибо большое!

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, что вы подразумеваете под «самим модулем mysql».

Comment: Смотрите логи запуска mysql. Размер БД тут не имеет значения, MySQL - это не in-memory БД.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете проверить сколько места занимает база данных использовав, к примеру, команду stat на папку с самой базой данных. А удалить данные из таблицы без подключения mysql не получится.